# How to bind Line.StrokeThickness property with Slider value in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a simple XAML file containing a canvas and a slider.

```
<Window x:Class="HitTesting.LineThickness"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="LineThickness" Height="300" Width="300">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Slider x:Name="mySlider" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" 
                Value="1" Maximum="2" Minimum="0.5">
        </Slider>
        <Canvas x:Name="myCanvas"></Canvas>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Now in my code behind, I want to bind the StrokeThickness property of the line to the slider value before adding it to canvas.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace HitTesting
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for LineThickness.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class LineThickness : Window
    {
        public LineThickness()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Line myLine = new Line() { X1 = 10, Y1 = 40, X2 = 100, Y2 = 40 , Stroke= Brushes.Green};

            // Here, I want to bind the StrokeThickness property of myLine to mySlider value.

            myCanvas.Children.Add(myLine);

        }
    }
}
```

I searched in lots of questions here, but it seems I can't get it right. I appreciate it if you point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding("Value");
myBinding.Source = mySlider;
myLine.SetBinding(Shape.StrokeThicknessProperty, myBinding);
```

Comment: This worked, thank you so much. How can I bind it to (1/Value) of the slider with this method? Is it possible? I want to define the thickness of the line relative to the inverse of the slider value, so I can keep it unchanged when zooming with slider later.

Comment: It's possible with `Binding.Converter` if you add another class implementing `IValueConverter` - check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @user2720372 Thanks, I'll look into that now. I'm new to wpf , this is great and all but it makes me feel like I know nothing about programming :p